# How to list all Rails 3 controllers and its public methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create a checking tool/rake task, that would dynamically go through all the public methods that are possibly accessible from outside world and check our authorization rules.

For this I would need to collect all the controllers and all its public methods. How to do that? I would like to use Ruby reflection or metadata techniques rather than grepping files.

Comment: it only makes sense if you have a catch-all rule like `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT this is impossible to do in the general case as you can't tell which params go where, e.g. `/items/foo/id` or `/items/foo?bar=baz` ? Also, which values of the params are ok ?

But you can get a decent value with

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:path)
```

which shall give you a list in the form used in rake routes  (`/klass/:id/action(.:format)`)

Comment: I will be checking just authorization rules (if its is present and what the rules are). Thanks

Comment: yes, I meant that for example you may have authorization for the edit of an item that is possible for administrators and for the users who originally created them but not for other users, which depends on a suitable choice of the params.